# When I send an email using the php mail function, I receive a copy of that email in my inbox, even though I didn't send it to myself

Tags: php, email, header, spam-prevention

Here's the code I'm using to send an email, with the hope that it's not going to be mistaken as spam:

```
# Set content-type for HTML
$Headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$Headers.= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

$From = 'Foo Bar <fbar@foobar.com>';

# Setting reply to email
$Headers.= 'From: '.$From."\r\n";
$Headers.= 'Reply-To: '.$From."\r\n";
$Headers.= 'Return-Path: '.$From."\r\n";

# Send
mail($_POST['Email'], $Subject, $Message, $Headers, "-f ".$From);
```

I'm using the "Return-Path" header & the "-f ".$From after the headers, as I've read these help the email to avoid spam filters.

Would anyone know why I'm getting emails sent to the $From address?